# Cannot create App Service managed certificate for traffic manager - CNAME record missing

Tags: certificate, azure-traffic-manager

I have two App Service instances behind a traffic manager profile. I managed to configure the 1st one (West Europe) without any issue. Among other things I created a managed certificate for the traffic manager DNS name. My problem is that when I try to do the same for the 2nd instance (North Europe) I get the following error:

> Hostname not eligible for App Service Managed Certificates creation. Ensure that your domain [trafficmngr-name].trafficmanager.net has an active CNAME record which is set to [app-service-2].azurewebsites.net.

Since the whole thing is managed and I do not use a custom domain name, I don't have any access to do any CNAME configuration myself. Of course, I didn't do such thing for the 1st instance which was configured without any problems.

I also exported the two instances as XML templates and compared them. They look identical except their names.

Any idea what's going on?

Here are a couple of screenshots.

[image: The Traffic Manager endpoints]

[image: The error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got the answer to my question but I managed to bypass the problem by using azure cli to do the exact same thing:

> az webapp config ssl create --name my-webapp-2 --resource-group my-group --hostname my-traffic-manager.trafficmanager.net